# PHP Regex print out and calculate values in specific column

Tags: php, regex

I have a file (file.txt) that I read with PHP.

**That's how it looks right now:**

```
<?php

$file = fopen("document/test.txt", "r");

if ($file === FALSE) {
    die("Nothing found.");
}

$sum = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $sum += (double) $data[11];
}
fclose($file);
echo "Total: " . $sum;

?>
```

Comment: If there are tabs - split line by `tab` and take the 12th element of an array.

Comment: `regex` is a tool too powerful and not appropriate for this job. [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) should be all you need.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are actually separated by tab characters? Based on your comments on the answer it sounds like it may be fixed-width data instead.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That could also be a possibility.. hmm

Comment: Just to clarify, can you copy an example row from the file and paste it into your question as-is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the 12th column in each line, and put's it into capture group 1.

`(?m)^(?:[^\t]*\t){11}([^\t]*)`

Formatted

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?: [^\t]* \t ){11}
 ( [^\t]* )             # (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are actually *tab delimited values*, a "dialect" of *csv*. PHP comes with [csv support](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
$fd = fopen("filename", "r");
if ($fd === FALSE) {
    die("Failed to open file");
}
$sum = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($fd, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $sum += (double) $data[11];
}
fclose($fd);
echo $sum;
```

Comment: I'll get that: Undefined offset

Comment: That means that your file has less than 12 columns. Or that the delimiter is space and not tab

Comment: It has way more than 12 columns. All in an Array

Comment: As I said, then it is probably not tab delimited data.

Comment: Oh, I see.. not all columns are separated by tabs, there are also ones who are separated only by a space key.

Comment: Is it possible to pre-process the file, with `sed` for example? Like this: `sed 's/ \{1,\}/\t/g' file`?

Comment: Alright, I updated my question, maybe it will be better to understand :)

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the data you are reading? I guess it is a fixed length csv dialect. Please make sure you exactly know the format of your input data (and what it means) and then come back and update your question.

Comment: Ok it's updated ;)

Comment: You wrote: `idk if there is a fixed length csv dialect`. You obviously need to find that out. Otherwise the file can't be reliably parsed. I mean I can come with a hack that splits by tabs or spaces, but how will you know that the resulting column 12 is not column 13 and column 5 is empty? You see my point?

Comment: Yes, i got it... I did a little trick where I imported the file into excel and every value is at the same spot. So it's a fixed length csv dialect :)

Comment: Ok. And what is the fixed length? How many chars? And where are the tabs coming from? Are they empty columns?

Comment: Yes there are empty columns. Its a file that gets exported.

Comment: Can you answer all the questions I've asked?